# Initialize a NSDate object with a specific time

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I have `time` in `string` format for example `2:00`. I want to initialize it to `NSDate` with present `date`.
I tried doing

```
   NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   [comps setHour:2];
```

I am not able to compare this with a date object. Please help

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:6];
[comps setMonth:5];
[comps setYear:2004];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

You should be able to compare with date after that.

Maybe you mean something like. I think will set using today's date and then you can create NSDateComponents from that and set time values.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
                    [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
[weekdayComponents setHour:12];
[weekdayComponents setMinute:10];
[weekdayComponents setSecond:30];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there a way of setting this only with time component the date needs to be present date.Will it be possible to change only the time component of Date object initialised using NSDate *mydate=[NSDate date];

Comment: I think you mean something like this.

Comment: Yes Thanks again for your quick reply.

Comment: NSTimeInterval Diff = [lastDate timeIntervalSinceDate:weekdayComponents];  This is giving me warning saying that Incompatible Objective-C types struct NSDateComponents expected struct NSDate.

Comment: I figured it out.I need to do NSDate *referenceTime = [gregoriant dateFromComponents:weekdayComponents];

Comment: just a quick correction: it should be
[weekdayComponents setSecond:30];

Answer (score 3):

To initialize an NSDate with the present date at 2, you'll have to split an NSDate with components year, month, and day, e.g.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian
                                       components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                       fromDate:today];
```

Set the hours to 2

```
weekdayComponents.hour = 2;
```

And then create a new NSDate by those components

```
NSDate *todayAt2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:weekdayComponents];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an `NSCalendar` object to convert `NSDateComponents` to an `NSDate`.  See Apple's documentation on [Creating a Date from Components](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Will it be possible to set the time component of NSDate.I can get an NSDate object initialized to present date and time.Will it be possible to change the time component after that.

Comment: Use the same calendar to turn the NSDate to NSDateComponents, then set the time, then use the calendar to turn it back into an NSDate.

Answer (score 1):

```
  func initializeDateWithTime(date:NSDate,hrs:Int,minutes:Int) -> NSDate{
    let today = date
     let gregorian:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
     let dateComponents = gregorian.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: today)

     dateComponents.hour = hrs;
     dateComponents.minute = minute;


     let todayAtX = gregorian.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
     return todayAtX!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bringing together some of the Objective C answers, I (now) have this helper function:

```
+ (NSDate*)dateForTodayAtHour:(NSUInteger)hour andMinutes:(NSUInteger)minutes {
    NSDate* today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents* weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:today];
    [weekdayComponents setHour:hour];
    [weekdayComponents setMinute:minutes];
    [weekdayComponents setSecond:0];
    NSDate* result = [gregorian dateFromComponents:weekdayComponents];
    return result;
}
```