# Objective C Calculate Amount of Time Between Now and 3:00

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimer

I am making an app to use at school and I want to make a countdown timer to countdown the amount of time between now and the end of school, which for me is 3:00. For example, at 11:15, it will read `3:45`.
So far, I have figured out how to make the countdown timer and I have the following code:    `countdownTimer.text = [Formatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];`
This code doesn't actually work yet, but I think it will work if I figure out how to subtract the current time from a set time and then use that value where `date` is, however I am open to other suggestions on how to approach the problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412234/create-nsdate-with-a-specific-time to create an `NSDate` for a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSCalendar` method `dateBySettingHour:minute:second:` to get the `NSDate` object associated with 3pm today:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *schoolOut = [calendar dateBySettingHour:15 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:now options:0];
```

There are lots of different ways to get the `NSDate` object associated with 3pm today, but the above is just one example. You could also use `components:fromDate` of [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar) to extract the `NSDateComponents` of `now`, then adjust the `hour`, `minute` and `second` and then create a new `NSDate` object using `dateFromComponents` (also a `NSCalendar` method).

Anyway, once you have a `NSDate` object that represents your target date/time, you can then use [`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html) to display the time interval between two dates in a nice format.

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;

NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:now toDate:schoolOut];
```

You can adjust the `unitsStyle` and `zeroFormattingBehavior` to adjust the format of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great. I have a slight follow up question, though. It displays the timer like "X Hours Y Minutes," (at noon it will say "3 Hours 0 Minutes"). I am very new to Objective C and not familiar with the NSDateComponentsFormatter, so I was wondering if it was possible to have it be formatted more like a regular clock (hh:mm:ss), including seconds? If not it still works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @willhunter2 - Change the `unitsStyle`. The default value of `NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional` should yield what you're looking for. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle